# How to specify data type in subprocess in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

After executing a command using subprocess gives out result in string type.

```
cmd = "ping -c 2  stackoverflow.com | grep -i icmp* |wc -l"
count = subprocess.check_output([cmd],shell=True)
count
'2\n'
type(count)
<type 'str'>
```

But i need this count in 'int' format,except typecasting it to "int(count)" ,how can i do this at subprocess command level ...is there any option to specify the data type in subprocess itself?

Answer (score 0):

Command output is always a string buffer. Just cast it to `int` if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess` communicates via raw data pipes, which are sent and received as `str` (`bytes` in Python 3). No other data type is possible. You just need to convert the result with `count = int(count)` as you mention in your question.